How to query cases with multiple pattern matching values in the same column
Ex Table:



Name
Location




John Smith
NewYork1131413431


John Smith
NewYork2222213


Marc White
Boston111118174124712


Sarah Phillips
NewYork2222123


Sarah Phillips
Boston2222918



I'm trying to query only the names in which they exist in 2 or more cities (for the case of this dataset, it will almost always be 2 cities max). So from this table, only Sarah Philips should return.
I wrote a query with the 'like NewYork% or like Boston%' operators with having count(location) > 1. But doing that would return John Smith as well because the NewYork string has multiple variations. The characters after the city name are also random in length.

You could make this simple by properly normalizing the data model. The city and the number that marks the location should be two columns.

If the data is always in this form, meaning the location consists of a town followed by some digits, you can use SUBSTRING with a regex check that fetches the substring before the first digit.
Then put this condition in the HAVING clause.
SELECT
  name
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY
  name
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(Location,'\D+')) > 1;

This will as requested only return those people who occur in different locations, see this sample fiddle.
Note: It would be better to save the city and the rest of the string (the digits) in separate columns, this would make things easier.
Another note: You need to extend this solution if you have more possible cases to cover.
For example, if the town NewYork is sometimes written as New York, you likely want to treat both as the same town.
Then you would add a REPLACE to get rid of the space and change the condition to ...HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(Location,' ',''),'\D+')) > 1
In case this is not sufficient and you need further assistance, please explain all possible cases you need to cover.

Hello another way to solve this in PostgreSql is by using Regexp_Peplace build in function:
This is one way with the help of having clause:
with data as (SELECT
    name
, regexp_replace(location, '[0-9]', '', 'g') AS location
FROM
    people_location
  )
select name 
  from data
group by name
having min(location)<>max(location);

This is another way using Exists operator:
with data as (SELECT
    name
, regexp_replace(location, '[0-9]', '', 'g') AS location
FROM
    people_location
  )
select distinct name 
from data pl
where exists (select * from data where pl.name=name and pl.location<>location);

You may also check the fiddle created for this case.
https://dbfiddle.uk/_cIOdooQ
Hope it helps.

One option is to use a table/view/cte containing city names. There should be some object with city names used in your location column. If you have it - use it. If not, you can define it as a cte:
WITH
  cities (id, city) AS
    ( Select 1, 'New York' UNION ALL 
      Select 2, 'Boston' UNION ALL 
      Select 3, 'Chicago' UNION ALL 
      Select 4, 'Austin' UNION ALL 
      -- ...
      Select 49, 'Las Vegas' UNION ALL 
      Select 50, 'Denver' 
    )

--      S Q L : 
SELECT    t.a_name
FROM    ( Select t.a_name, t.location, c.city
          From   tbl t
          -- handle space characters, casing and possible other differences between city name and  location
          Left Join cities c ON(POSITION(Upper(Replace(c.city, ' ', '')) IN Upper(t.location) ) > 0)
        ) t
GROUP BY  t.a_name
HAVING   Count(Distinct t.city) > 1

/*    R e s u l t : 
a_name
---------------------
Sarah Phillips        */

See the fiddle here.
